# Problems outputting text image with PHP

Tags: php, imagettftext

I've to print some text on the screen as an image with PHP in a page, but it only shows a white square.

Here is the code of the main page:

```
    <?php
    SESSION_START();
    if ($_SESSION["log"]!=true){
    //die("<h1><center>Non sei loggato come amministratore</center></h1>");
    header('location:index.php'); }

   include('ase.php');
    echo ('
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <body>
                <a href="./logout.php">Logout</a>
                <img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($stringdata) . '">
                </body></html>');
      ?>
```

And here the code of the page that should output the image:

```
 <?php 
    // Set the content-type
    header('Content-Type: image/png');

    // Create the image
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor(800, 2000);

    // Create some colors
    $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 800, 2000, $white);

    // The text to draw
    $text = "Read the text and the questions below. For each question mark 
    the letter next to the correct answer - A,B,C or D.";

    // Replace path by your own font path
    $font = 'arial.ttf';


    // Add the text
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

        ob_start();
        imagepng($im);
        $stringdata = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    ?>
```

(sorry for my english)

Comment: Instead of (probably what you are doing) including the script and messing with output buffering, set the php script as image source url and then output the image normally without output buffering. Destroy the GD object after `imagepng` with `imagedestroy($im);`.

Comment: if you don't want do what Charlotte Dunois suggest (and you should do it) just remove `header('Content-Type: image/png');`.

Comment: Thanks to @Federico, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've resolved the problem removing the header ( `header('Content-Type: image/png');` ).